# Ignore empty textInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am fairly new to Shiny. In the following app, I would like to be able to render a data table if only one of the two `textInput` boxes is filled in. The app works fine if both boxes are filled in. But I would like the data table to only render one variable if only one variable is filled in (e.g. only the X variable name is entered in and only the X variable data shows up in the table).

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example 01"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      textInput("x", "X Variable"),
      textInput("y", "Y Variable")
    ),

    mainPanel(

      dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  tabledata <- reactive({
    x <- mtcars %>% select(input$x) * 2
    y <- mtcars %>% select(input$y) * 3

    if (is.null(x) == TRUE){y}
    if (is.null(y) == TRUE){x}
    else {cbind(x,y)}

  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable(tabledata())

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For testing, I've been entering `mpg` as the X variable and `cyl` as the Y variable. If you're wondering why I am using `textInput` instead of `selectInput`, it is because the project I'm using this for has 100,000+ search options (musical artists).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because if one of the input is empty, it is not really empty but a `character(0)`, or `""`, if you prefer.  So, R tries to select a column being named `""` and fails.

Then, you have to exclude the empty strings `""` of your the column list that you want to display.

I have simplified your code a little and added a "trigger" button to display the table. (That way, you can wait to have typed `C - Y - L` to display the data. Otherwise, the code tries to subset the dataframe at every typed character).

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example 01"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      textInput("x", "X Variable"),
      textInput("y", "Y Variable"), 
      actionButton("print", "print table")
    ),

    mainPanel(

      dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  tabledata <- eventReactive(input$print, {

    x <- mtcars %>% select(if(input$x == "") NULL else {input$x}) * 2 # I don't use if_else because it has side effects to return a NULL value
    y <- mtcars %>% select(if(input$y == "") NULL else {input$y}) * 3

    if (ncol(x) == 0){y}
    if (ncol(y) == 0){x}
    else {cbind(x,y)}

  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable(tabledata())

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you simplifying the code, but unfortunately in my project the inputs cannot be combined in a vector that easily; they are modified first. To reflect that with this example, I've gone back to the original code and changed `mtcars %>% select(input$x)` to `mtcars %>% select(input$x) * 2` and multiplied by 3 for y. Apologies for not making this clear in the initial post. How would you go about it if the input was modified and you have to keep `x` and `y` as stored values?

Comment: OK, then I made an edit to my answer to stick to your syntax. The philosophy remains the same, though. For commodity reasons I kept the triggering button, but of course you can get rid of it!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking if x is blank (which as @Jrm_FRL points out would be achieved with `input$x==''`, you could sidestep that and just check of x is a name of an actual column or not:

```
x <- if(input$x %in% colnames(mtcars))  mtcars %>% select(input$x) * 2
```

Do the same for `y`, and the rest of your code should work as is.