# Dealing with a blank input for an R shiny object with multiple inputs

Tags: r, shiny

Trying to build my first Shiny app, but I'm running into difficulty with navigating multiple inputs.

I have a formulary dataset with the following cols:

`names(dat) <- c("Code","Drug","DIN", "Description", "Price", "Plan")`

The idea is to be able to return the dataset by drug coverage plans, which users select from input "PlanType".

Where I'm running into trouble is with the second inputs of selecting either a category ("ProductID") or entering a drug "Name" (which is done as a str_detect against the "Description" col -- for some reason the primary dataset has very incomplete data in the "Drug" col). Both ProductID and Name inputs have to be entered or it returns an error.

```
#This works when both fields are completed
dat %>% 
    filter(Code == input$ProductID) %>% 
    filter(str_detect(Plan, input$PlanType)) %>%
    filter(str_detect(Description, input$Name))
```

I can get it working with either function alone by removing one of the inputs. However, users may want to search the category without a specific drug in mind, or search for a specific drug without knowing the specific category.

I have searched previous similar questions and have tried incorporating their solutions as below, but can't seem to get it working. I think that I'm probably missing something fairly fundamental here, but may have exceeded my abilities and understanding here.

Thanks in advance for your help

Dataset:
https://novascotia.ca/dhw/pharmacare/documents/Excel-Format-Formulary-for-Vendors.xlsx

```
# Dependencies

library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)

# Import Dataset
dat <- read_excel("Excel-Format-Formulary-for-Vendors.xlsx", sheet = 1)
dat <- dat[,c(1,2,3,4,6,8)]
names(dat)
names(dat) <- c("Code","Drug","DIN", "Description", "Price", "Plan")

#Some ugly code to clean up the Code col

dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
      str_detect(dat$Code,"^A"),
      "Alimentary tract and metabolism")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
    str_detect(dat$Code,"^B"),
    "Blood and blood forming organs")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
    str_detect(dat$Code,"^C"),
    "Cardiovascular system")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
    str_detect(dat$Code,"^D"),
    "Dermatologicals")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
    str_detect(dat$Code,"^G"),
    "Genito-urinary system and sex hormones")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
    str_detect(dat$Code,"^H"),
    "Systemic hormonal preparations, excluding sex hormones")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
      str_detect(dat$Code,"^J"),
      "General antiinfectives, systemic")      
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
      str_detect(dat$Code,"^L"),
      "Antineoplastic and immunomodulating agents") 
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
      str_detect(dat$Code,"^M"),
      "Musculo-skeletal system")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
      str_detect(dat$Code,"^N"),
      "Nervous system")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
      str_detect(dat$Code,"^P"),
      "Antiparasitic products, insecticides and repellents")       
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
      str_detect(dat$Code,"^R"),
      "Respiratory system")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
      str_detect(dat$Code,"^S"),
      "Sensory organs")
dat$Code <- dat$Code %>% 
  replace(
      str_detect(dat$Code,"^V"),
      "Various")

# UI 

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Project Titlee"),
   
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             selectInput("ProductID", "Class", choices = dat$Code)),
      column(3,
        textInput("Name", "Drug Name")),
      column(3,
             selectInput("PlanType", "Drug Plan:", 
                         c("Seniors' Pharmacare"="S",
                           "Community Services Pharmacare" = "F",
                           "Drug Assistance for Cancer Patients" = "C",
                           "Diabetes Assistance Program" = "D",
                           "Exception status applies" = "E"
                           ), selected=NULL)) ),
    fluidRow(
      column(9, tableOutput("Drug")),
      column(3, "some text"))
    )



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected <- reactive( 
                  dat %>% 
                      filter(Code == input$ProductID) %>% 
                      filter(str_detect(Plan, input$PlanType)) %>%
                         if (exists("Name") && Name != ""){
                                filter(str_detect(Description, input$Name))
                                      })
  output$Drug <- renderTable(
    selected()
  )}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Update:**
I also tried the following (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61897694/ignore-empty-textinput-in-r-shiny)),  which allows ProductID to work but returns Null for textinput:

```
    selected <- reactive({
    y <- dat %>% select(if(input$Name == "") NULL 
            else filter(str_detect(Description,{input$Name})))
      
        if (ncol(y) == 0){dat %>% 
            filter(Code == input$ProductID) %>% 
            filter(str_detect(Plan, input$PlanType)) }
        
        else { dat %>% 
            filter(Code == input$ProductID) %>% 
            filter(str_detect(Plan, input$PlanType)) %>%
            filter(str_detect(Description, y))} })
```

**Update 2**

I'm been trying to work with the filtering method and if/else outside the pipes, but I feel like I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be. It's also returning *"Can't subset columns with `if (...) NULL`."*, which I think is due to the use of the *select* function but I've kind of lost my way here.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected <- reactive( 
    
    {
         x <- dat %>% 
            filter(str_detect(Plan, input$PlanType)) 


        y <- dat %>% 
                select(if(input$ProductID == "") NULL 
                      else {x %>% 
                            filter(Code == input$ProductID) })         
      
         z <- dat %>% 
                select(if(input$Name == "") NULL 
                       else {x %>%           
                           filter(str_detect(Description, input$Name))})
          
                
        if (ncol(y & z) == 0){x}
        else {
          if (ncol(z) == 0){y}
          if (ncol(y) == 0){z}
          else {
            dat %>% 
            filter(Code == input$ProductID) %>% 
            filter(str_detect(Plan, input$PlanType)) %>%
            filter(str_detect(Description, input$Name))
          }
          
        }
    })
```

If anyone can help me out I'd be very grateful! Thanks

Comment: Your question is not reproducible because you've not given us any data.  That said, your probem is that `if` is a statement.  It doesn't belong in a pipe.  The solution is to filter in two stages.  First, on `input$ProductID` and `input$PlanType`.  Save the result to an object.  Then, conditional on `input$Name` not being `NULL`, filter again.

Comment: Thanks, I was worried that may be a problem, but didn't want to overwhelm people with too much stuff not directly related. I have edited my question to be reproducible with the dataset.

Comment: *Amended the post*

Comment: You probably want `input$Name != ""` instead of `exists("Name") && Name != ""`. But you can't include this `if` in the filters chain as you do.

Comment: @Limey thanks for the help. I think I'm getting lost on the two step filtering, despite playing around with it for a while. Any other pointers? Thanks

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thanks, I've removed that now, but still struggling to get my unconditional filtering to work outside the %>% as you suggested. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewrite your code in order to optimize it

First stop : if you copy/paste more than 2 times, you need a function. Here you can use `switch` and `sapply` for each of you categories.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)

# Import Dataset
dat <-
    read_excel("Excel-Format-Formulary-for-Vendors.xlsx",
               sheet = 1)
dat <- dat[, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8)]
names(dat)
names(dat) <-
    c("Code", "Drug", "DIN", "Description", "Price", "Plan")


#Some  awesome code using switch and sapply
dat$Code <-
    sapply(X = substr(dat$Code, 1, 1), function(first_letter) {
        switch(
            first_letter,
            A = "Alimentary tract and metabolism",
            B = "Blood and blood forming organs",
            C = "Cardiovascular system",
            D = "Dermatologicals",
            G = "Genito-urinary system and sex hormones",
            H = "Systemic hormonal preparations, excluding sex hormones",
            J = "General antiinfectives, systemic",
            L = "Antineoplastic and immunomodulating agents",
            M = "Musculo-skeletal system",
            N = "Nervous system",
            P = "Antiparasitic products, insecticides and repellents",
            R = "Respiratory system",
            S = "Sensory organs",
            V = "Various"
        )
    })
```

Second stop : easy fix, dont forget the `input$` tag. I also add the "All" category in order to show the selection reactivity.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Project Title"),
    
    fluidRow(
        column(
            6,
            selectInput(
                inputId = "ProductID",
                label = "Class",
                choices = c("All", unique(dat$Code))
            )
        ),
        column(3,
               textInput(inputId = "Name", label = "Drug Name")),
        column(
            3,
            selectInput(
                inputId = "PlanType",
                label = "Drug Plan:",
                c("All",
                  "Seniors' Pharmacare"="S",
                  "Community Services Pharmacare" = "F",
                  "Drug Assistance for Cancer Patients" = "C",
                  "Diabetes Assistance Program" = "D",
                  "Exception status applies" = "E"
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    fluidRow(column(9, tableOutput("Drug")),
             column(3, "some text"))
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
    selected <- reactive({
        select_dat <- dat
        
        if (input$ProductID != "All") {
            select_dat <- select_dat %>%
                filter(Code == input$ProductID)
        }
        
        if (input$PlanType != "All") {
            select_dat <- select_dat %>%
                filter(str_detect(Plan, input$PlanType))
        }
        
        if (input$Name != "") {
            select_dat <- select_dat %>%
                filter(str_detect(Description, regex(input$Name, ignore_case = T)))
        }
        select_dat
    })

    output$Drug <- renderTable(selected())
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope this helps you to get better understanding of R and RShiny

Comment: thank you for your help. Your improvements and advice make a lot of sense.